# How to add newline in output buffer?

Tags: c

How do we add new line to output buffer using printf in C?

Like in c++ we use endl, what do we use in C?

```
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: You need to give us some hint (at least) of what you have tried. There are many possible answers to this question, but they depend on the context.

Comment: @Adrian I wrote "endl" in my question above. I think "\n" is the correct way as mentioned by someone below. I am very new to programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this  printf("whatever message you want \n")
"\n" added at the end output a new line in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You want the character `\n`.

If you're calling something like

```
printf("hello");
```

you can either include the `\n` character in the string:

```
printf("hello\n");
```

or you can print it with a separate call to `printf`:

```
printf("hello");
printf("\n");
```

or you can print it using `putchar`:

```
printf("hello");
putchar('\n');
```

It's up to you, and there are other ways to do it, too.

(But notice that in the last example I used single quotes around `'\n'`, because `putchar` prints a single character, not a string.)

Comment: You forget the must obvious: `puts` :P